# Comparing primitives for exact equality

Tags: apex

Is there any way to compare two primitives to find out if they are not only the same value but actually the same object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operator you're looking for is ===. It doesn't work on pure primitive entities, but it does work on references to those entities. The opposite test is !==.

```
Object a = 5, b = 5;
if(a === b) {
    System.debug('A and B are the same object.');
} else {
    // This will be output
    System.debug('A and B are not the same object.');
}

Object a = 5, b = a;
if(a === b) {
    // This will be output
    System.debug('A and B are the same object.');
} else {
    System.debug('A and B are not the same object.');
}
```

If you try to use Integer directly, for example, you'll get a compile error:

```
Integer a = 5, b = 5;
if(a === b)  {  // compile error, "equality only allowed for reference types"
```

Comment: Wow, I missed an obvious one. I never thought to simply store my primitive as Object. Thanks, you win!

Comment: @BobRoberts For what it's worth, *I had no idea this would work.* It was something of a hunch, and I was surprised when my debug logs confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the new Type methods?

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_equals

Will this accomplish what you are looking to do?