# Exact equality operators only allowed for reference types: String

Tags: apex, error, visualforce, compile-error

Please find below piece of code where I am getting this error.

Error:

> Compile Error: Exact equality operators only allowed for reference
>   types: String

Code:

```
if(((inc.Status_abv__c!=='New') || (inc.status_abv__c == 'Under Review')) && change1==false ) //
        { ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Your selected Compliance Incident : '+inc.Name+' is not having Status as \'New\'!'));
        pagemsg=true;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `!==` which besides the values also checks the same location in memory. You can use that only on references but not primitives - [check this answer.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44118/comparing-primitives-for-exact-equality)

You need to use `!=` instead to compare values only.